# Why does `1.ordinalize` work in locales :en & :fr but not in :de in Ruby on Rails with rails-i18n gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

In Ruby on Rails the ordinalize method does not work in the :de locale. The error given is:

```
 > 1.ordinalize
=> "translation missing: de.number.nth.ordinalized"
```

It is easy to reproduce this:

1. Create a brand new rails application with the command `rails new test1`
2. Install the `rails-i18n` gem by adding it to the Gemfile and running `bundle`
3. Copy and edit the config/locale/en.yml to create fr.yml and de.yml
   with the following edits:

```
    ==> config/locales/de.yml <==
    de:
      hello: "Hallo Welt"
    
    ==> config/locales/en.yml <==
    en:
      hello: "Hello world"
    
    ==> config/locales/fr.yml <==
    fr:
      hello: "Bonjour le monde"
```

Then try and use ordinalize in rails console:

```
test1 git:(main) ✗ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 7.0.4.3)
3.1.2 :001 > I18n.locale
 => :en
3.1.2 :002 > 1.ordinalize
 => "1st"
3.1.2 :003 > I18n.locale = :fr
 => :fr
3.1.2 :004 > 1.ordinalize
 => "1er"
3.1.2 :005 > I18n.locale = :de
 => :de
3.1.2 :006 > 1.ordinalize
 => "translation missing: de.number.nth.ordinalized"
```

Looking at the rails-i18n source there appears to be code there to handle the `number.nth.ordinalized` translation key in [German](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/ordinals/de.rb) and [French](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/ordinals/fr.rb)

If I manually add a `number.nth.ordinalized` key into my de.yml file then that translation is found.

Please can someone help me understand why this is not working and ideally explain what needs to change to make it work.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: If it is a bug that is easily reproduced why not file an issue report on the github? Will certainly get more eyes on it from people who work on the gem that way.

Comment: Thanks @Beartech. I initially intended to raise this as a discussion on github, but the project doesn't have a discussions page, and I'm not completely sure that it is a bug. Hence I thought I'd try my luck here.

Comment: Protip: use the [Rails bug reporting templates](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/main/guides/bug_report_templates) next time. They make it easy to write completely self contained examples which can be verified without any manual steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last release (7.0.6) of the rails-i18n gem was in November last year.  The German ordinal code [was added in February of this year.](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/commit/dfb470e44c5b6d28222078d752c2dadb0b9a56a8)

You can wait for a release **or** switch to the main branch by changing the line in your Gemfile to:

```
gem 'rails-i18n', github: 'svenfuchs/rails-i18n', branch: 'master'
```

After which you should be able to get:

```rb
[2] pry(main)> I18n.locale = :de
=> :de
[3] pry(main)> 1.ordinalize
=> "1."
```

Comment: Thank you @tgf. I completely failed to think of that possibility. I've [raised a request](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/issues/1076) to see if the rails-i18n team would be willing to release a new version with that code in it.